# rewrite engine does not work suitable

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have problem in using RewriteEngine
I would like to display suitable url in browsers when users come to my site.
instead of this one:

```
http://charcharkhkala.com/products.php?title=proName&carID=0013
```

I want to display this one :
http://charcharkhkala.com/products/proName

OR
http://charcharkhkala.com/products/proName/0013

and my htaccess code is :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)/(.*)$  products.php?title=$1&carID=$2 [nc,L]
```

I have searched the entire internet but I haven't got proper answer.

Comment: "I have searched the entire internet but I haven't got proper answer." No, you haven't :) You have searched to the full amounts of your efforts :)

Comment: maybe you are true but I haven't reach to complete answer yet !! have U got any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)/(.*)$  products.php?title=$1&carID=$2 [nc,L]
```

only applies to URLs with at least 2 `/`. That's not your general case, and also, URLs typically start with `/`, so use `^/products/...`.

Comment: Thank a lot. I tested the rule which you were written But it didn't work ,I changed my code but i didn't do any special. anyway Thank again my friend. I hope you will be successful in programming world.

Comment: you mean I should use for example this one www.site .com/folder/products.php?title=proName&carID=0003 and for htsccess =>  RewriteRule ^/products/(.*)/(.*)$  /folder/products.php?title=$1&carID=$2 [nc,L] I tried that but didn't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

hora! I found the right answer

to address link in the first page you should have this:

```
<a href="products/proName/0003" title="title">proName</a>
```

and for htaccess this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine OnRewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^products/(.*)/(.*)$ ./products.php?title=$1&carID=$2
```

and if you still have problem to load page perfect add this code to head tag, because of css and js file (top of css and js address)

```
<base href="http://yourdomain.com/" />
```

have fun and be careful when coding :)